# How to use open/openvt with command line arguments?

Tags: ssh

Question:

I can start LumiSoft mailserver in console mode like this:

```
./lsMailServer.exe -daemon
```

Unfortunately this blocks the terminal that was used.
And I am logged in via ssh.

I'm just experimenting with the server, so I need to restart a lot after configuration changes.

Normally, I'd use the open command in this circumstance, which normally works fine.

It also works fine, when I do open ./lsMailServer.exe with X-Forwarding.

But I want to run the server terminal-only, which requires the -daemon option.
Now when I do

```
open opt/MyPath/lsMailServer.exe -daemon
```

I get the following error message:

> open: invalid option -- 'd' Usage: openvt [-c vtnumber] [-f] [-l] [-u]
>   [-s] [-v] [-w] -- command_line

How can I use open with a program + arguments for that program ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aaaaah,forget it, one only needs to add -- after open:

```
openvt -- ls -l
```

or

```
open -- /opt/LumiSoft/Debug/lsMailServer.exe -daemon
```

respectively

Comment: I was writing an answer just with this information. Anyway, you definitely must give a look and a try to `GNU screen`.